# XSD restriction for string value

Tags: xsd, restriction

I need to write a restriction for a string column, so that it will include 20 letters and 3 of the following : (. , -).

How can this be done?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<xs:element name="someString">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xs:pattern value="([\w]*[\.\,\-]?[\w]*[\.\,\-]?[\w]*[\.\,\-]?[\w]*)"/>
        <xs:length value="23"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

**Explanation:**

`[\w\.\,\-]{0,20}` match a single character present in the list below

- Quantifier:

  Between 0 and 20 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

  - \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
  - \. matches the character .literally
  - \, matches the character , literally
  - \- matches the character - literally

So basically this will match all these

1. aabbbcaabbbcaabbbcac,,-
2. ,,-aabbbcaabbbcaabbbcac
3. dd,aabbbc-aabbbc,aabbbc

The `length value="23"` forces that the total string be 23 characters and the regex forces that three characters of the total length be between comma, hyphen and period.

Comment: Can you explain it please? What is \w and why should it work? Thank You.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg I've added explanation. You can also try this here at http://regex101.com/

Comment: This doesn't restrict the number of letters to 20 and the number of .,- to 3.